# Time complexity while with unknown value

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I have a queue with an unknown size `queue<int> q;`

What is the time complexity of this while loop?

```
while(!q.empty())
{
count<<q.front();
q.pop();
}
```

I don't know the size of q, how could I know the time complexity?

Comment: why do you think you would need to know the size of `q` to know the time complexity of the loop? The time complexity is a function of a variable(s), in this case it's a function of the length of the queue.

Comment: I would say O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You time complexity is determined in terms of a variable, in your case that is the number of elements in the q, it's call it n. So you need to visit each element once and only once, so you get O(n).

Answer (score 2):

[std::queue::front](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/front)

> #### Complexity
>
> Constant

[std::queue::pop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop)

> #### Complexity
>
> Equal to the complexity of Container::pop_front.

The default container for std::queue is std:dequeue so

[std::deque::pop_front](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_front)

> #### Complexity
>
> Constant

Think about how many times you repeat these operations and you get your complexity.